# Plumbing in new shower

Tags: plumbing

I'm trying to connect my new electric shower unit up. Unfortunately both the connections have threaded connections. I bought a straighter coupler but this seems to be the opposite of what I want.

This is the existing elbow joint.
[image: existing elbow joint]

This is my failed attempt to bridge them with a straight coupler. Posted to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. [image]

Sorry, this is probably the stupidest question ever. I'm new to plumbing.

Comment: I just posted an answer, but had another question.  What _was_ attached to that elbow coming out of the wall?  It looks like it might not be standard pipe thread, and in that case, the elbow may need to be replaced before doing anything else.

Comment: That is not a "*coupler*", it's a "*hex nipple*".  A coupler would have two female ends, not two male ends.

Comment: Hey JPhi1618 thanks for your response! This is what was attached before, it's from the old shower unit that I'm replacing. http://i.imgur.com/70nYE5D.jpg

Comment: I've been looking at parts to replace the existing elbow with and found this one http://www.screwfix.com/p/yorkshire-tectite-sprint-street-elbow-15mm/63054

Comment: Yea, looks like that elbow is custom-made for the old valve and will most likely need to be replaced.  You can try and screw female pipe thread onto it, but I doubt they are the same size.  What type of pipe is coming out of the wall?  Copper?  Threaded?  That will determine your replacement options for the elbow.  The "Tectite" (also known as "Sharkbite") replacement elbow you have shown may not be a good choice because they will freely rotate when installed, so you new valve would just rotate at the whim of gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using Copper Pipe 15mm. Used a 15mm pipe cutting tool to make a tiny piece. Then I used 2  15mm nuts / 15mm olives on either end and managed to bridge the gap.

I also added a 15mm isolation value so I can work on the shower in the future without having to isolate the entire house from the mains.

[image: end result]

Comment: Cool that the elbow turned out to be something you could reuse.  Make sure that shower control is mounted securely - all those compression fittings may not stand up well to flexing or movement.  The isolation valve is also a great idea - glad there was room for it.

Answer (score 4):

Warning, U.S. English ahead.  What you purchased would be known as a "nipple", which is a short piece of pipe with male threads on both ends.  You wanted a "coupler" which has female threads on both ends.  I'm not sure if nipple and coupler are used outside of the U.S., but they have specific meanings here.

However, a threaded coupler will normally only work when the piece you are connected can be screwed in (like connecting two straight pipes).  Since the valve you are connecting too looks like it's connected to the shower unit, you're not going to be able to rotate it around in place to screw it into the elbow in the wall.

What you *really* need is called a "union", and looks like this:

[image: Pipe union]

The two ends of the union can be separated and screwed onto the elbow and valve separately.  Then, the large "nut" in the center is used to join the two halves without rotating either end.

Comment: I asked about the threads because it looks like there could have been a previous shower valve there that used a union-type connector.  There's not really a standard for those, so I bet the elbow needs to be replaced.